# Iterating a list within a pyspark column to explode and add additional rows

Tags: python, pyspark

I'm very new to pyspark, so please forgive me if this is super simple.
I have some data in a pyspark dataframe that looks something like this:

```
team            stats                                                                established year
Mariners        [name, Ken Griffey Jr., hrs, 630, hits, 2781, ab, 9801, rbi, 1836,   1977
                 name, Edgar Martinez, hrs, 309, hits, 2247, ab, 7213, rbi, 1261...]
```

The number of players inside the stats list cannot be assumed, but will always have the same 5 key/value pairs (name, hrs, hits, ab, rbi).

I want to 'explode' this list for every team to look like this:

```
team        name               hrs   hits.   ab.   rbi.   established year
Mariners    Ken Griffey Jr.    630   2781    9801  1836   1977
Mariners    Edgar Martinez     309   2247    7213  1261   1977
...
...
```

Originally, the data type under stats was just a string, but I have successfully converted that column into arraytype using split and regex. I read up and tried using the explode function in pyspark, but I'm not getting the intended results.

My feeble attempt at trying to use explode for this:

```
#first to get the column formatted as an ArrayType
df = df.withColumn("stats_array", F.split(F.regexp_replace("stats", r"(^\[)|(\]$)", ""), ", "))

df = df.select("team", "established_year", "stats_array")

#my attempt at using explode
df = df.withColumn("explody", F.explode("stats_array"))
```

This results in the data looking like this:

```
team        established_year   stats_array                         explody
Mariners    1977               [name, Ken Griffey Jr., hrs,        name
                                630, hits, 2781, ab, 9801, rbi, 
                                1836, name, Edgar Martinez, hrs, 
                                309, hits, 2247, ab, 7213, rbi, 
                                1261...]

Mariners    1977                [name, Ken Griffey Jr., hrs,        Ken Griffey Jr.
                                630, hits, 2781, ab, 9801, rbi, 
                                1836, name, Edgar Martinez, hrs, 
                                309, hits, 2247, ab, 7213, rbi, 
                                1261...]

Mariners    1977                [name, Ken Griffey Jr., hrs,        hrs
                                630, hits, 2781, ab, 9801, rbi, 
                                1836, name, Edgar Martinez, hrs, 
                                309, hits, 2247, ab, 7213, rbi, 
                                1261...]

Mariners    1977                [name, Ken Griffey Jr., hrs,        630
                                630, hits, 2781, ab, 9801, rbi, 
                                1836, name, Edgar Martinez, hrs, 
                                309, hits, 2247, ab, 7213, rbi, 
                                1261...]

""            ""                               ""                   hits
```

etc...

Is there a way to use the explode function to get what I want? I want the key value pairs to be column name and stat for every 5 key/value pairs, because after every 5 will be the stats of a new player.

Comment: Can you provide the code that you've used and what the current output looks like?

Comment: hi added some code I have been trying.

Comment: Is something like this even feasible in pyspark, or would it rather be better to use something like a python reader/writer to process line by line?

Answer (score 0):

Please try this.

**# explode to get required format**
'''

```
import pyspark.sql.functions as F
df=df.withColumn('exploded', F.explode('stats'))

# get the name and the name in separate columns
df=df.withColumn('name', F.col('exploded').getItem(0))
df=df.withColumn('hr', F.col('exploded').getItem(1))
....
...
...
'''
```

Comment: This doesn't quite make sense to me. Once we explode the stats column, the new 'exploded' column will be a column of strings. Calling .getItem on a column of strings throws an error like Can't extract value from exploded#569: need struct type but got string;